# Trouble with displaying MarkJS matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a jquery search (mark.js) that highlights words on a page based on user input. I'm able to highlight the results, but the results do not display i.e. "1 of 1 matches". The matches should appear in `<span class="kwt-count"> matches</span>`. I am not sure how to get it to work. Here is my JSFiddle:

```
<div class="header">
  Search:
  <input type="search" placeholder="Lorem">
  <button data-search="next">&darr;</button>
  <button data-search="prev">&uarr;</button>
  <button data-search="clear">✖</button>
  <span class="kwt-count"> matches</span>
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis eu ullamcorper orci, eget p</p>
</div>


<script>
var lstEl = null;
var cntr = -1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSearch').click(function() {
        lstEl = null;
        cntr = -1;
        var vl = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
        $("#bodyContainer").removeHighlight();
        $("#bodyContainer").highlight(vl);
    });

    $('#btnNext').click(function() {
        alert(cntr);
        if (lstEl === null) {
            lstEl = $('#bodyContainer').find('span.highlight');
            if (!lstEl || lstEl.length === 0) {
                lstEl = null;
                return;
            }
        }
        if (cntr < lstEl.length - 1) {
            cntr++;
            if (cntr > 0) {
                $(lstEl[0]).removeClass('current');
            }
            var elm = lstEl[cntr];
            $(elm).addClass('current');
        } else
            alert("End of search reached!");
    });

    $('#btnPrev').click(function() {
        alert(cntr);
        if (lstEl === null) {
            lstEl = $('#bodyContainer').find('span.highlight');
            if (!lstEl || lstEl.length === 0) {
                lstEl = null;
                return;
            }
        }
        if (cntr > 0) {
            cntr--;
            if (cntr < lstEl.length) {
                $(lstEl[cntr + 1]).removeClass('current');
            }
            var elm = lstEl[cntr];
            $(elm).addClass('current');
        } else
            alert("Begining of search!");
    });
});

$(function() {

  // the input field
  var $input = $("input[type='search']"),
    // clear button
    $clearBtn = $("button[data-search='clear']"),
    // prev button
    $prevBtn = $("button[data-search='prev']"),
    // next button
    $nextBtn = $("button[data-search='next']"),
    // the context where to search
    $content = $(".content"),
    // jQuery object to save <mark> elements
    $results,
    // the class that will be appended to the current
    // focused element
    currentClass = "current",
    // top offset for the jump (the search bar)
    offsetTop = 50,
    // the current index of the focused element
    currentIndex = 0;

  /**
   * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
   */
  function jumpTo() {
    if ($results.length) {
      var position,
        $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
      $results.removeClass(currentClass);
      if ($current.length) {
        $current.addClass(currentClass);
        position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, position);
      }
    }
  }

/**
   * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
   */
  function jumpTo() {
    if ($results.length) {
      var position,
        $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
      $results.removeClass(currentClass);
      if ($current.length) {
        $current.addClass(currentClass);
        position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo(0, position);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Searches for the entered keyword in the
   * specified context on input
   */
  $input.on("input", function() {
    var searchVal = this.value;
    $content.unmark({
      done: function(totalMatches) {
        $content.mark(searchVal, {
          separateWordSearch: false,
          acrossElements: true,
          done: function(totalMatches) {
            $results = $content.find("mark");
            currentIndex = 0;
            jumpTo();
            var tag = field.find('[data-tag="' + keyword.toLowerCase() + '"]'),
            html = keyword;
                tag.addClass('active');
                if (totalMatches) {
                html += '<span class="kwt-count">' + totalMatches + '</span>';
                }
        tag.find('content').html(html);

          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  /**
   * Clears the search
   */
  $clearBtn.on("click", function() {
    $content.unmark();
    $input.val("").focus();
  });

  /**
   * Next and previous search jump to
   */
  $nextBtn.add($prevBtn).on("click", function() {
    if ($results.length) {
      currentIndex += $(this).is($prevBtn) ? -1 : 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = $results.length - 1;
      }
      if (currentIndex > $results.length - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      jumpTo();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

JSFiddle link: [MarkJS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dude12go8/zbf0g8e1/50/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for your comment:

Declare 2 new below variables on top:-

```
var variableCounter=0;
var totalCount=0;
```

Add below 2 events in document.ready function

```
$("[data-search=next]").click(function(){

   if(variableCounter<totalCount)
     variableCounter=variableCounter+1;
   else
    variableCounter=1;

    $(".kwt-count").html(variableCounter+ " of " +totalCount+" Matches");
})

 $("[data-search=prev]").click(function(){

   if(variableCounter>1)
     variableCounter=variableCounter-1;
   else
       variableCounter=totalCount;

   $(".kwt-count").html(variableCounter+ " of " +totalCount+" Matches");
})
```

Update below existing events:-

```
$input.on("input", function() {
var searchVal = this.value;
$content.unmark({
  done: function(totalMatches) {
    $content.mark(searchVal, {
      separateWordSearch: false,
      acrossElements: true,
      done: function(totalMatches) {
        $results = $content.find("mark");
        currentIndex = 0;
        jumpTo();
        //var tag = field.find('[data-tag="' + keyword.toLowerCase() + '"]'),
        //html = keyword;
            //tag.addClass('active');
        totalCount=totalMatches;
            if (totalMatches) {
            //html += '<span class="kwt-count">' + totalMatches + '</span>';

          variableCounter=1;
          $(".kwt-count").html(variableCounter+ " of " +totalMatches+" Matches");
            }
        else
        {
           $(".kwt-count").html(" Matches");
        }
    //tag.find('content').html(html);

      }
    });
  }
});
```

});

```
$clearBtn.on("click", function() {
$content.unmark();
$input.val("").focus();

variableCounter=0;
totalCount=0;
 $(".kwt-count").html(" Matches");
```

});

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated code.Need to change only input event

```
$input.on("input", function() {
var searchVal = this.value;
$content.unmark({
  done: function(totalMatches) {
    $content.mark(searchVal, {
      separateWordSearch: false,
      acrossElements: true,
      done: function(totalMatches) {
        $results = $content.find("mark");
        currentIndex = 0;
        jumpTo();
        //var tag = field.find('[data-tag="' + keyword.toLowerCase() + '"]'),
        //html = keyword;
        //    tag.addClass('active');
            if (totalMatches) {
        //    html += '<span class="kwt-count">' + totalMatches + '</span>';
            $(".kwt-count").html(totalMatches+ " of " +totalMatches+" Matches");             

          }
        //tag.find('content').html(html);


      }
    });
  }
});
```

});

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Akash! Is there a way to make it disappear and have it jump to i.e. 1 of 30 mathes" click on the next button "2 of 30 matches"... and vise versa when the user clicks on the previous button

Comment: Just tested it out. Works wonderfully! I also added the ability to scroll up and down the page.